# i need set flag in model save before event and get in model save after event in magento 2

Tags: magento2, resource-model, object, crud

I have Create two event model save before and after i get specific object and set flag in before model and get in after model.
for example 
in before model

```
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {   
            $obj = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
            if ($obj instanceof \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer)
            {    
             $this->isNew = is_null($obj->getId());
             //var_dump($this->isNew);die; //true     
             return;
            }
}
```

in after model

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
 {   
     var_dump($this->isNew); die; //Null
 }
```

Comment: You can also set registry and get registry to identify your flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 provides a method for this: `isObjectNew()`

Thus you can do the following in both `beforeSave()` and `afterSave()` methods:

```
if ($this->isObjectNew()) {
    // New object
}
```

Examples from Magento 2 core files:

- in `beforeSave()` : https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Time/Created.php#L37
- in `afterSave()` : https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/CatalogRule/Model/Rule.php#L507

Comment: i need to pass flag in specific object so i add it in variable i don't need to check object is new.

Comment: @Pratik well your flag is called `$isNew` so I assumed that's what you wanted to do

Comment: yes you are right i found it thx.